# Angular - What is the most neat way to maintain and structurize interfaces?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, interface

I am developing an application with Ionic / Angular. In order to handle HTTP responses, I created an interface to manage the JSON response. I added this interface called `interface IOne` at the bottom of my file. Like:

```
export Class Example { 

  private getExample() {
    this.http.get(url, {}, {}).then((result) => { const data: IOne = result.data; });
    return data;
  }

}  

export interface IOne {
  name: string;
}
```

In the future several Interfaces will be created as multiple HTTP requests with different response-types will be made by me. In this way there will be a very long list of interfaces under my `Class Example` and **this is not neat (I assume?)** It will be looking like this:

```
export Class Example { }  

export interface IOne {
  name: string;
}

export interface ITwo {
  age: number;
}

export interface IThree {
  color: string;
}
```

I've thought about creating 1 file called **interfaces.ts** and importing this file into **example.ts**. Is this a good solution? Are there better alternatives? So concretely:

**What is the best way to manage and structure multiple interfaces so that I can maintain a good project structure?**

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular CLI then you can generate a library in which you put all shared resources for one or more projects in the same structure.

Simply run this command in your project root:

```
ng generate library shared
```

Now you will see a new folder called `projects` in which you have a `shared` folder as well.

In this `shared` folder you can put whatever you want and then expose them via the `public_api.ts` file, you will see how it's done with a few examples.

To watch your `shared` library run:

```
ng build shared --watch
```

Importing stuff in your main app is then as easy as doing:

```
import {MyInterface} from 'shared';
```

Make sure to run `ng serve` **after** you've run the build command for `shared` or it won't exist in the `dist` folder, which will cause your main app to show an error saying it can't find `shared`.